# populating dropdownlist from another dropdown selection in ASP.Net Web Form

Tags: asp.net, sqldatasource

I am trying to Populate data into the Company DropDownList after selecting the Country from the CountryDropDownList. Complete newbiew on ASP.Net Web Form. So please excuse little knowledge.

I have been trying to do it only on the .aspx page which I am not entirely sure if I could do it. My code is as follows, which doesn't populate anything on the CompanyDropDownList at all. The problem is I have been writing the code looking at different sources but I guess I am not entirely sure where the problem is and what am I doing wrong. If anyone can explain a little bit and spot my errors would be really helpful.

```
                   <asp:DropDownList 
                        ID="CompanyDropDownList" 
                        runat="server" 
                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="CompanyDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged"
                        DataSourceID="CompanyNameSqlDataSource" 
                        DataTextField="CompanyName" 
                        DataValueField="CompanyID" 
                        AppendDataBoundItems="True" 
                        AutoPostBack="True">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource 
                        ID="CompanyNameSqlDataSource" 
                        runat="server" 
                        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:BIGroupCostConnectionString %>"
                        OnSelecting="CountryNameSqlDataSource_Selecting" 
                        SelectCommand="SELECT CompanyName, countryID FROM Company Where CompanyID = @CompanyID">
                        <SelectParameters>
                            <asp:ControlParameter 
                                Name="CountryID"
                                ControlID="CountryDropDownList" 
                                PropertyName="SelectedValue"
                                Type= "String"/>
                            <asp:Parameter Name="CountryID" />
                        </SelectParameters>
                     </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are passing the company drop-down as parameter instead of the country you mention.

```
 <SelectParameters>
   <asp:ControlParameter Name="CompanyID" ControlID="CompanyDropDownList" 
    PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type= "String"/>
 <asp:Parameter Name="CompanyID" />
```

Shouldn't it be your Country control?

Ademar

Comment: Tried this, but still no luck I am afraid.

Comment: You also have to change your SQL query that is expecting a parameter @CompanyID when you are passing the CountryID. e.g:

"...Where countryID = @CountryID"

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. The problem was the following line of code. Removing the line showed the data correctly.

```
<asp:Parameter Name="CountryID" />
```